# How to display nested lists like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have lists nested within lists like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Rings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bracelets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Earrings</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Diamond Earrings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hoop Earrings</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Necklaces and Pendants</a>
    ...
</ul>
```

The lists are floated left. The nested lists are defaulted to not be displayed. So it ends up looking like this:

[image]

This so far I have. Now what I want to do is whenever a list is hovered that has a nested list (for example *Earrings*). I want the nested list to be revealed like so:

[image]

Notice what all is going on here, **its not just telling the nested list to be displayed, that would not look right.** Its putting them in a block between the first level lists where they wrap (between "Sports Jewelry" and "Charms").

I am not sure how to go about this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I think would be to create different lists, for each line. Something like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Rings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bracelets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Earrings</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Diamond Earrings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hoop Earrings</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Necklaces and Pendants</a>
    ...
</ul>
<ul><li><a href="#">Charms</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mens Jewelry</a></li>
     ....
```

So when you hover a `li` of the first line, the inner `ul` will be appear above the second line according to the normal flow.

To hide the inner `ul`, you can use the `display:none` as initial state, and show it using `ul li:hover {display:block; }`

Comment: I see what you are saying, and that could probably work if the lists were going to be static. Unfortunately they are going to be generated dynamically. So I would need some way of determining at run time where the wrap is going to occur to insert a </ul><ul> between each line.

Comment: probably you can write a jquery script that will find the width of the li items. When the X li item is the last of the first row (you can find it calculating the the total width of li's and compare it with the width of ul) then the script add in the code the code </ul><ul>

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your hover change the sublist from `display:none` to `display:block`.

It should be something like this:

```
ul li ul { display: none; }
ul li:hover ul { display: block }
```

That won't show at all when it's not hovered, and will add space between list items when you hover.

You probably also need to do some absolute positioning to make it appear below the hovered item, otherwise it will push the things beside it down as well.